# Getting "Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices"" when using linq2db with .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, sybase, linq2db

I'm using `linq2db` with .Net Core, but I'm getting the follow when trying to connect with database:

> Message = "Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."

I tried to solve this by importing manually the `dll` that I've found at this location:

> C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a

But that didn't work.

Before that I was getting a similar error, but that was about the `Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient`, I solved downloading and adding the reference to this `dll`.

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but I've follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db)

Comment: It seems linq2db is not .net core compatible. My advice is to target the full framework in your application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could solve the error by using a different approach to connect:

```
public MyContext() : base(new SybaseDataProvider("Core"), "You connection string here") { }
```

Before that I was trying to implement the `ILinqToDBSettings` file, but as I saw inside the code of `linq2db` there is a comment about that incompatibility:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not a linq2db issue. Sybase provider doesn't support .net core and you need to use DataAction's AdoNetCore.AseClient for .net core applications.
Linq2db supports it starting from version 2.1.0 : https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/wiki/Releases-and-Roadmap#dataaction-adonetcoreaseclient-provider-support

Comment: Please, see the instructions I mentioned on the questions, there are explicitly instructions to use with .Net Core.